# Groovy - GPars - Active Object - Active Method which returns a value

Tags: groovy, gpars

In Groovy, I need to implement an ActiveObject instance called `MyCounter` so that the following code would pass:

```
final MyCounter counter = new MyCounter()
counter.incrementBy 10
counter.incrementBy 20
counter.update 'Hello'
assert 35 == counter.value
```

I have come with the two implementations listed below - none of them works.

1.

```
@ActiveObject
class MyCounter
{
    private int counter = 0

    @ActiveMethod
    def incrementBy(int value)
    {
        println "incrementBy $value"
        counter += value;
    }

    @ActiveMethod
    def update(String value)
    {
        println "update $value"
        counter += value.size();
    }

    int getValue()
    {
        println "getValue"
        return counter;
    }
}
```

I suppose that this does not work because the calls to `incrementBy` don't block, e.g. the value property and thus the counter variable is in fact accessed before the incrementBy operations finish.

2.

```
@ActiveObject
class MyCounter
{
    private int counter = 0

    @ActiveMethod
    def incrementBy(int value)
    {
        println "incrementBy $value"
        counter += value;
    }

    @ActiveMethod
    def update(String value)
    {
        println "update $value"
        counter += value.size();
    }

    @ActiveMethod
    int value()
    {
        println "getValue"
        return counter;
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that:

> Non-blocking methods must not return a specific type, use def or void instead

Comment: is this involving GPars?  if so, you should perhaps add that as a tag and include in body/title somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on the assumption this is GPars, you should be able to use your first implementation with the following code:

```
final MyCounter counter = new MyCounter()
def x1 = counter.incrementBy 10
def x2 = counter.incrementBy 20
def x3 = counter.update 'Hello'
x1.get() //block
x2.get() //block
x3.get() //block
assert 35 == counter.value
```

You may need to provide more information as to exactly what you intend to happen with regard to flow of execution to get better info.

You can also change your annotations to be indicate blocking:

```
@ActiveMethod(blocking=true)
```

See relevent [docs](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/5.%20Actors.html#5.4%20Active%20Objects) for info on any of the above.

Answer (score 1):

The first example has a race condition, since getValue() directly touches unprotected internal state of the object, while both incrementBy() and update() use the active object's internal actor to modify the object's state.

In the second example, since non-blocking methods return instaces of Promise, you are not allowed to provide a specific return type, such as int.

In-line with what Brian suggests, just annotate the getValue() method with `@ActiveMethod(blocking=true)`, which will allow you to give a specific return type.

```
@ActiveMethod(blocking=true)
int getValue() {...}
```